# some mistake made by me with mybatis(MySql) dynamic statement

Tags: mybatis

Some mistake made by me with mybatis(MySql) dynamic statement:[image]
It is showing error Dynamic should be initialized.

```
SELECT * from studentdetails 
<dynamic prepend="WHERE ">
  <isNotEmpty prepend="AND" property="gender">
     GENDER = #{gender}
  </isNotEmpty>

  <isNotEmpty prepend="AND" property="interestedin">
     INTERESTEDin = #{interestedin}
  </isNotEmpty>
</dynamic>
```

Comment: i was trying to post  SELECT * from studentdetails 
 <dynamic prepend="WHERE ">
      <isNotEmpty prepend="AND" property="gender">
         GENDER = #{gender}
      </isNotEmpty>
  
      <isNotEmpty prepend="AND" property="interestedin">
         INTERESTEDin = #{interestedin}
      </isNotEmpty>
   </dynamic>

Comment: What `ORM` framework did you use exactly? `Mybatis` or `iBatis`?

Comment: If you using `myBatis`, I think the sql in screenshot of your post is right, but `dynamic` or `isNotEmpty` is not supported by `myBatis`, you should use these two tag in `iBatis`.